# Sencha Touch 2 Nested list not displayed

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I'm trying to display NestedList with json on my hard disk, but it is not displayed. What am I doing wrong? No bugs in Chrome. (Chrome open with `Applications / Google \ Chrome.app / Contents / MacOS / Google \ Chrome - allow-file-access-from-files`). I get a blank screen without a single error in the console. If I comment `fullscreen: true,` in MyPanel.js I get clear NestedList without any data.

Servlet.json

```
{
    "stream":[{
            "post_id": "1",
            "post_type": "text",
            "post_thumb": "bla1"
        }]
}
```

MyPanel.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
    alias : 'widget.MyPanel',

    config: {
        store : 'Storere',
        title: 'NestedList Example',     
        detailCard: {
            html: 'You can see detail information here!'
        } 
    } 
});
```

Storere.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Storere', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
        defaultRootProperty : 'stream',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '.\/app\/Servlet.json',
            reader: {
                type:         'json',
                rootProperty: 'stream'
            }
        }
    }    

});
```

MyModel.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name:'post_id', type: 'string' },
            {name:'post_type', type: 'string' },
            {name:'post_thumb', type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});
```

TheWorld.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.TheWorld', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        profile: Ext.os.deviceType.toLowerCase(),
        control: {
            'MyPanel': {
                activate: 'onActivate',
                leafitemtap: 'onDetailDisplay'
            }
        }  

    },

    onActivate: function() {
        console.log('Main container is active');
    },

    onDetailDisplay: function(nestedList, list, index, target, record) {
        console.log('onDetailDisplay is active');
        var detailCard = nestedList.getDetailCard();
    },

    onItemTap: function(view, list, index, target, record, event) {
        console.log('Item was tapped on the Data View');
    },

    init: function() {
        console.log('Controller initialized');
    },
});
```

**UPD:**
[image]
[image: after click first item]

Comment: can u post complete json ?

Comment: this is complete json, I want to test this way, finally json and model will have another look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `NestedList` config to following.

```
config: {
    store : 'Storere',
    //displayField:'post_type',
    title: 'NestedList Example',
    listConfig          : {
        itemTpl: '{post_type}'
    },
    detailCard: {
        html: 'You can see detail information here!'
    }
}
```

There is this `displayField` config of `NestedList` where you can specify which field to be used to set title and item text . By default it is set to text but you can specify it to be one of your model field. If you are overriding `getItemTextTpl` or `getTitleTextTpl`, this config will be ignored.

Plus there's `listConfig` config option available where you can mention `itemTpl` config. As json is having multiple fields with image and text nodes I assume you want to show that too.

So you can have `listConfig` something like following :

```
    listConfig: {
        itemTpl: '<div><img src="{post_thumb}">{post_type}</div>'
    },
```

Reasons of list was not getting displayed might be-

1. Store is not loaded with proper data. ( To make sure inspect *Network* tab in chrome to see if `Servlet.json` present.
2. `displayField` and/or `listConfig` not mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for fast and perfect answer! It works =) But there is new bug in my logic (UPD in question). If a list item is a leaf after clicking on it again displays the entire list.

Comment: if you set `leaf:true` in json you've received for all leaf items then it won't happen.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot to understand and correct the code!